# TextFormField's value resets after pressed enter with TextEditingController()

Tags: android, flutter, firebase-authentication

**Code Links:**

- [Main.dart](https://github.com/Lunari8546/eLesson/blob/4168beb1f03017460e1a39540e2055e046855877/lib/main.dart)
- [Auth.dart](https://github.com/Lunari8546/eLesson/blob/4168beb1f03017460e1a39540e2055e046855877/lib/views/auth.dart)
- [Fieldwithicon.dart](https://github.com/Lunari8546/eLesson/blob/4168beb1f03017460e1a39540e2055e046855877/lib/widgets/inputs/fieldwithicon.dart)

Also, when I pressed enter. It didn't move to another field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The value of **TextEditingController** resets because you are instantiating it inside the build method, so everytime the tree is rebuilt, your controller will be instantiated again.
So to solve this problem just declare your controllers outside the build method:

```
class _AuthState extends State<Auth> {
  final emailController = TextEditingController(); //right here
  final passwordController = TextEditingController();
```

And to move the cursor to another field you will need to use **FocusNode** and some function that is called when the user press enter, like onEditingComplete:

```
class _AuthState extends State<Auth> {
  final emailController = TextEditingController();
  final passwordController = TextEditingController();

  final emailNode = FocusNode();
  final passNode = FocusNode(); //the nodes to request focus and move the cursor
```

Receive the func and the focusNode as parameters, and also, you don't need to use a stateful widget here:

```
class FieldWithIcon extends StatelessWidget {
  final String buttonText;
  final IconData buttonIcon;
  final FocusNode node;
  final VoidCallback onEditingComplete;
  final TextEditingController controller;
  final bool obscureText;

  FieldWithIcon({
    this.buttonText,
    this.buttonIcon,
    this.controller,
    this.obscureText,
    this.node,
    this.onEditingComplete,
  });

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
          border: Border.all(color: Color(0xFFBC7C7C7), width: 2),
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(50)),
      child: Row(
        children: <Widget>[
          Container(
            width: 60,
            child: Icon(
              buttonIcon,
              size: 20,
              color: Color(0xFFBB9B9B9),
            ),
          ),
          Expanded(
            child: TextFormField(
              onEditingComplete: onEditingComplete,  //the func/callback
              focusNode: node,  //the node to request focus
              controller: controller,
              autocorrect: false,
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                border: InputBorder.none,
                hintText: buttonText,
                hintStyle: GoogleFonts.titilliumWeb(),
              ),
              maxLines: 1,
              obscureText: obscureText,
              validator: (input) {
                if (input.isEmpty) {
                  return "Invalid";
                } else {
                  return null;
                }
              },
            ),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Now pass the function/callback and the focus node to your fields:

```
FieldWithIcon(
  buttonText: "Input your Email",
  buttonIcon: Icons.email,
  controller: emailController,
  node: emailNode,
  onEditingComplete: () => passNode.requestFocus(), //requesting focus of the next field
  obscureText: false,
),
SizedBox(height: 20),
FieldWithIcon(
  buttonText: "Input your Password",
  buttonIcon: Icons.vpn_key,
  controller: passwordController,
  node: passNode,
  onEditingComplete: () => passNode.unfocus(), //unfocus the field when enter is pressed
  obscureText: true,
),
```

Comment: Thanks it worked! However, I want to ask why I need to use Stateless widget instead of Stateful widget? Is there a difference between them?

Comment: The main diference is that Stateful has a State and Stateless no. So as you are just passing parameters to the text field there is no need to use a stateful, because the state will not change, for example, you will not use a set state inside the text field to rebuild it. You can learn more about Stateless and Stateful [here](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/ui/interactive).